# While loop index error

Tags: python, indexing, while-loop

I want Python to constantly scan a folder and as soon as a new file is created in the folder to start the rest of the code.

However I am stuck here:

```
import os

os.chdir("path")
a = os.listdir("path")
initial = len(a)


while True:
        b = os.listdir("path")
        final = len(b)
        if final > initial:
                c = list(set(b) - set(a))
                a.append(c[0])
```

c[0] is appended to list a however the code then crashes with this error

> ```
> a.append(c[0]) IndexError: list index out of range
> ```

Comment: `print()` the value of `c` before the line `c = list(set(b) - set(a))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `c` is empty. So the easiest way to make this line work is:

```
import os

os.chdir("path")
a = os.listdir("path")
initial = len(a)

while True:
    b = os.listdir("path")
    final = len(b)
    if final > initial:
        c = list(set(b) - set(a))
        if c:
            a.append(c[0])
```

And `while True` without `break` statement is not that good idea...

Comment: I did not add break because I want the script to run indefinitely. As files will be added multiple times a day.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

os.chdir("path")
a = os.listdir("path")
initial = len(a)

while True:
    b = os.listdir("path")
    final = len(b)
    if final > initial:
        c = list(set(b) - set(a))
        a.extend(c)
```

Few points
 1. Good idea to add few seconds on sleep inside the while loop.
 2. What happends if a file is deleted and a new file is added(might not be a valid scenario)